# arithmetic and geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$a,b,c$ ,are consecutive arguments of a given arithmetic progression. $a^2, b^2, c^2$, are  consecutive arguments of a geometric progression. With this information given, find the $q$ for the geometric progression.

I compiled two equations here based on the known properties of these progressions, however ended up with polynomials of high degrees, which didn't help at a solution..

Comment: Write the condition for the geometric progression as $a^2c^2 = (b^2)^2$.

Comment: So I did..that fourth degree isn't very nice at all

Comment: If you write it $b^4 = (b^2-d^2)^2$, it's nice enough ($d$ is the difference of the arithmetic progression).

Answer (score 2):

You have $a+c=2b$ and $a^2c^2=b^4$. From the latter, $\pm ac=b^2$. Hence $a,c$ are roots of either $X^2-2bX+b^2=0$ (which makes $a=c=b$, so $q=1$) or of $X^2-2bX-b^2=0$, which makes them $b\pm b\sqrt{2}$, so $q$ is $1\pm \sqrt 2$.
All three solutions are indeed possible:

$$ a=1-\sqrt 2, b=1, c=1+\sqrt 2\qquad a^2=3-2\sqrt 2, b^2=1, c^2=3+2\sqrt 2$$ 
$$ a=1+\sqrt 2, b=1, c=1-\sqrt 2\qquad a^2=3+2\sqrt 2, b^2=1, c^2=3-2\sqrt 2$$ 
and of course
$$ a=b=c=1\qquad a^2=b^2=c^2=1$$

Comment: What about a=b=c=0?

Comment: Where did you get the quadratic equation from?